# How to find the equilibrium distribution of a discrete time Markov Chain

Tags: markov-process

I want to find the all the equilibrium distribution of this markov chain
[image: Transition matrix]

By letting w1= α, where 0<= α <=1, I got
w2= (7/15)α
w3 = (2/3)α
w4= (3/5)α

But I am not sure if its correct.

Also, does this Markov chain has limiting distribution?

Comment: can you show your calculations as well

Comment: If this is homework, you should probably add the [tag:self-study] tag as well.

Comment: Hints: Obviously ergodic because $\mathbf{P}$-matrix has all positive elements. Stationary distribution (4-vector with elements summing to 1) with $\sigma$ with $\sigma\mathbf{P} = \sigma.$ But notice that $\mathbf{P}$ is doubly stochastic (that is columns as well as rows sum to $1).$

Answer (score 1):

#### Eigenvectors and eigenvalues

For an equilibrium distribution, you have

$$P \cdot v = \lambda v \quad \text{where $\lambda = 1$}$$

So you will need to look for the eigenvector $v$ that relates to the eigenvalue $1$.

You can compute it by solving the following [homogeneous system of linear equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Homogeneous_systems)

$$(P-\lambda) v =  \begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{1}{2}-\lambda&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{8}&\frac{1}{8} \\
\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{8}-\lambda&\frac{1}{8}&\frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{8}&\frac{1}{8}&\frac{1}{2}-\lambda&\frac{1}{4} \\
\frac{1}{8}&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{8}-\lambda \\
\end{bmatrix} v = 0$$

which you could do by writing the matrix in [row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) with [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination)

#### Sudoku

Maybe you are supposed to solve it like above, but note how the values are distributed and see how the matrix looks like a sudoku or a magic square (all rows and columns sum up to 1).

Can you use this knowledge to easily think of an eigenvector with eigenvalue 1?

#### Solving with computer code

You can solve the above problem automatically and fast with a computer.

```
m <- rbind(c(4,2,1,1),
           c(2,1,1,4),
           c(1,1,4,2),
           c(1,4,2,1))/8
eigen(m)
```

which gives

> ```
>  $values
>  3  1.0000000  0.3952847  0.2500000 -0.3952847
> ```

> ```
>  $vectors
>       [,1]       [,2] [,3]       [,4]
>  [1,] -0.5  0.6979762 -0.5 -0.1132660
>  [2,] -0.5  0.1132660  0.5  0.6979762
>  [3,] -0.5 -0.6979762 -0.5  0.1132660
>  [4,] -0.5 -0.1132660  0.5 -0.6979762
> ```

#### Limiting distribution

> Does this Markov chain has limiting distribution?

The starting vector can be written as a sum of the eigenvectors

$$x_0 = a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + a_3 v_3 + a_4 v_4 $$

Then you will have:

$$\begin{array}{}
x_1 &=& P \cdot x_0\\ &=& P \cdot (a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + a_3 v_3 + a_4 v_4) \\&=&  a_1 \lambda_1 v_1 + \lambda_2 a_2 v_2 + \lambda_3 a_3 v_3 + \lambda_4 a_4 v_4
\end{array}$$

and you can continue this reasoning to

$$x_n = \lambda_1^n a_1 v_1 + \lambda_2^n a_2 v_2 + \lambda_3^n a_3 v_3 + \lambda_4^n a_4 v_4$$

Now consider the limiting behavior for the values of $\lambda_i^n$ and argue which value $x_n$ will converge to for $n \to \infty$

Comment: equilibrium distribution is the probability vector so all the values should be positive and they all should sum up to 1, but in your solutions there are negative values.

Comment: @bluelagoon you can rescale eigenvectors however you like. The R function scales them such that the length (mean square of the components) equals 1. If $P\cdot v = v$ then also $P \cdot (cv) = (cv)$